# What is the best way to clean string from html tags

Tags: go

There is a string, for instance.
What is the best way to clean the string from `html` content?

```
s := "<b>John</b> Thank you."
```

The result should be `Thank you.`

Comment: Shouldn't the desired output be `John Thank you.` ?

Comment: @icza Shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to slice the string is to search for a specif string, 
(at your case `"</b>"`) and separate him to a different string.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    html := "<b>John</b> Thank you."
    fmt.Println(html)
    thanks := strings.Split(html, "</b>")[1]
    fmt.Println(thanks)
}
```

Result:  Thank you.

Play ground link:https://play.golang.org/p/yOc3G0YeNTe

Also please consider `TrimSpace` to prevent unnecessary spacing

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    html := "<b>John</b> Thank you."
    fmt.Println(html)
    thanks := strings.Split(html, "</b>")[1]
    fmt.Println(thanks)
    cleanThanks := strings.TrimSpace(thanks)
    fmt.Println(cleanThanks)
}
```

Result:

```
 Thank you.

Thank you.
```

Play ground link:https://play.golang.org/p/S7BRM7jOvtL

**Please note that you should verify the string contain `"</b>"` if not you will get panic: runtime error: index out of range**

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please resist using Regular Expressions. Bad things [can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) .

On a more serious note, if you *can't trust* the HTML content, I suggest using something like [bluemonday](https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday), which is currently what you could be using in production.

For a simpler approach, to get something working quickly you could use either another library such as [grokify/html-strip-tags-go](https://github.com/grokify/html-strip-tags-go) which will suit your needs, or as in Eitam's answer roll your own by splitting the strings.

Best of luck!

Comment: I agree using Regular Expressions isn't recommended ,
Great note,
but sometimes you cannot avoid it , just important to remember to verify the string before trying to slice him.